# Regarding Regular Expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I have not done regular expression in php.

I need to replace Three Backslashes (\\\) with Null character ('').

So anybody can help me to resolve this in php?

Example:

1. \\\ replace with null ('')
2. \\\\ replace with \

Thank guys for reply but it is still not working.

Comment: Why regex? Regex would only make sense if you want to keep runs of backslashes that are longer than 3, i. e. remove \\\ but keep \\\\.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
preg_replace('/\\\\\\\\\\\\/', "\x00", $input)
```

Each `\` needs to be escaped for PHP as `\\` and again for PCRE as `\\\\`, so three backslashes are `\\\\\\\\\\\\`.

You might want to work with `preg_quote` instead:

```
preg_replace('/'.preg_quote('\\\\\\', '/').'/', "\x00", $input)
```

Comment: I think OP meant the empty string `''`, when he wrote »null character« – although I was confused by this bit too

Answer (score 1):

Why not `str_replace()`?

The pattern is so simple that `str_replace()` does the job

```
$new  =  str_replace('\\\\\\', '', $old);
```

Check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: You need six backslashes in the pattern string. In your version the first pair form a backslash, then `\'` embeds a single-quote. There is then no string terminator.